# Laravel backpack edit form displaying checklist items with selected values from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

In my crud controller, There is one field called "roles (Multiple checklist)", While before saving the roles, I am converting array into string like `1,2,3` using implode.
Ex: CrudController
`setUp()` method

```
$options = [
                'name' => 'roles',
                'label' => 'Roles',
                'type' => 'checklist',
                'entity' => 'roles',
                'attribute' => 'name',
                'model' => "Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Models\Role",
            
            ];
        
        $this->crud->addField($options);
```

In Store method,

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        $sel_roles = $request->input("roles");

        $roles = !empty($sel_roles) ? implode(",",$sel_roles) : "";

        $request->request->set("roles",$roles);       

        //dd($request);
        return parent::storeCrud($request);
    }
```

Edit Method looks like this,

```
public function edit($id) {

        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('update');
        // get the info for that entry
         $this->data['entry']= $this->crud->getEntry($id);
         $options = [
            'name' => 'roles',
            'label' => 'Roles',
            'type' => 'checklist',
            'entity' => 'roles',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model' => "Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Models\Role",
        
        ];
    
        $this->crud->addField($options);

         $this->data['crud'] = $this->crud;
         $this->data['fields'] = $this->crud->getUpdateFields($id);

         $this->data['id'] = $id;

         return view('crud::edit', $this->data);

    }
```

If am trying to access, Edit page, I am getting below error,

**ErrorException in line 15:
Call to a member function pluck() on string (View: /var/www/html/app/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/fields/checklist.blade.php)**

`checklist.blade.php` page looks like below

```
<div @include('crud::inc.field_wrapper_attributes') >
    <label>{!! $field['label'] !!}</label>
    <?php $entity_model = $crud->getModel(); ?>

    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($field['model']::all() as $connected_entity_entry)
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                      name="{{ $field['name'] }}[]"
                      value="{{ $connected_entity_entry->id }}"

                      @if( ( old( $field["name"] ) && in_array($connected_entity_entry->id, old( $field["name"])) ) || (isset($field['value']) && in_array($connected_entity_entry->id, $field['value']->pluck('id', 'id')->toArray())))
                             checked = "checked"
                      @endif > {!! $connected_entity_entry->{$field['attribute']} !!}
                  </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    {{-- HINT --}}
    @if (isset($field['hint']))
        <p class="help-block">{!! $field['hint'] !!}</p>
    @endif
</div>
```

How do I display the roles with selected values in the edit page.

Thanks

Comment: The error is inside `checklist.blade.php` and you are not showing it in your question

Comment: `checklist.blade.php` file in vendor backpack folder, It is expecting some format. But I am unable to send that expected format like in the add page. Still required that page, will update again `checklist` page

Comment: Is expecting an array...

Comment: @Raffobaffo, updated checklist page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of debug and verified,

Send the edit values in the collection format,

```
 $options = [
            'name' => 'role_id',
            'label' => 'Roles',
            'type' => 'checklist',
            'entity' => 'roles',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model' => "Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Models\Role",
            "value" => collect([$edit_value_array])
        
        ];
```